# как в Vlang сделать get запрос с header?

Tags: get, v

в заголовке всё описал

```
import net.http

fn main() {
    url := 'http://212.183.159.230/10MB.zip'
    header := http.new_custom_header_from_map({'Range': 'bytes=0-10'})?
    res := // тут запрос
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json
import net.http


fn main() {
    config := http.FetchConfig{
        header: http.new_header(key: 'Range', value: 'bytes=0-10')
    }

    url := 'http://212.183.159.230/10MB.zip'

    resp := http.fetch(http.FetchConfig{ ...config, url: url }) or {
        println('failed to fetch data from the server')
        return
    }

    mystruct := json.decode(MyStruct, resp.text) or {
        println('failed to decode MyStruct json')
        return
    }

    println(mystruct)
}
```

[доки с примерами](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/master/examples/get_weather/get_weather.v) 
[доки с тестами](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/51d7aede68c2b3ac4b7db76c1d60741bb6db58a4/vlib/net/http/header_test.v)

Comment: `header: http.new_header(key: http.CommonHeader.range, value: 'bytes=0-10')`